# T-SQL Insert into truncates data on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is odd. I have two separate store procedures inserting into one table.

One works fine while the other truncates all but the 1st character on four `varchar(50)` columns. I've tested this by executing the SP in SQL.

Only difference is the working query is moving data from one table to the other. The non-working stored procedure is receiving parameters. In the non working query, there are `int` columns and they work fine. It's just the four varchar.

This works fine.

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderItems_tbl (POID, VendorAccountID, POTicketID, POInvItemID, POLineItemQty, PartManufPartNum, PartOrderDesc, PartOrderManufacture, PartOrderModel, POType, PODescription, POStatusID, PartRequestedBy, POGLCode)
    SELECT
        POID, VendorAccountID, PartOrderTicketID, PartInvID, 
        POItemQty, PartManufPartNum, PartOrderDesc, 
        PartOrderManufacture, PartOrderModel, POType, 
        PODescription, POStatusID, PartRequestedBy, POGLCode
    FROM
        PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl
```

This is the non working stored procedure:

```
Procedure [dba].[xxxxx]
(
    @POID int,
    @VendorAccountID int,
    @PartOrderTicketID int,
    @PartInvID int,
    @PartManufPartNum varchar,
    @PartOrderDesc varchar,
    @PartOrderManufacture varchar,
    @PartOrderModel varchar,
    @PartOrderType varchar,
    @PartOrderQTY int   
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderItems_tbl
    ([POID],[VendorAccountID],[POInvItemID],[POTicketID],[PartManufPartNum],[PartOrderDesc],[PartOrderManufacture],[PartOrderModel],[POLineItemQty])

VALUES  (@POID, @VendorAccountID, @PartInvID, @PartOrderTicketID, @PartManufPartNum, @PartOrderDesc, @PartOrderManufacture, @PartOrderModel, @PartOrderQTY)

END
```

I am completely baffled as I see nothing wrong and the qry does not error.

Thanks in advance folks

Comment: Defining your sproc inputs as just VARCHAR limits them to 1 character.

Comment: `varchar` is **1** char long, `varchar(n)` is **n** chars long,  add a size.

Comment: This is a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: You are correct. I've been at this app 18 hours a day to meet a deadline. Lost in translation.. Thank you needed a second pair of eyes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stored proc does not specify the *length* of the varchar inputs - by default this length is 1.

```
procedure [dba].[xxxxx]
(
    @POID int,
    @VendorAccountID int,
    @PartOrderTicketID int,
    @PartInvID int,
    @PartManufPartNum varchar(50), -- match the column length
...etc
```

Comment: You are correct. I've been at this app 18 hours a day to meet a deadline. Lost in translation.. Thank you needed a second pair of eyes :)